# Project Name.MacOs.csproj won't load in Mono or Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

I have a solution that has 6 projects in it, all of them are .csproj types and load just fine except this one, MONO is pretty unclear on the error but VS says "The project type is not supported by this installation"  The project file in the solution bar is greyed out and when you click the arrow to drop down the files in the project it says this file cannot be loaded.  Does anyone have a clue as to what might cause this?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the only times I've seen this is when I try to load a solution with ARM projects in it and the ARM SDK is not installed on the development box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't load on the mac either. I think i found the problem though.  I am attempting to use some Cocoa interop in my .net code.  In order to do this, I must use a library called monobjc, I did not have that installed so there is that problem.  From there though, for anyone else having this problem, monobjc's libraries are only compatible with 2.8 and 2.6 of mono. It turns out 2.6 and 2.8 are kind of hard to find laying around.

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: I would recommend using the "MonoMac" Cocoa bridge instead of MonoObjC. MonoMac is included with MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

From the name, I'd guess it's a MonoMac project. It'll load in MonoDevelop, but only on MacOS.